# How do I connect to a WSDL web service using PHP and retrieve its contents?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

So I'm at a blank here, never used PHP ever and was tasked with something that I would think is easy, connect to a wsdl webservice , username and password are supplied ,and display all the contents recieved on a web page, but I'm at a blank.

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://soapserver.example.com/blahblah.asmx?wsdl"); 

// Prepare SoapHeader parameters 
$sh_param = array( 
            'Username'    =>    'username', 
            'Password'    =>    'password'); 
$headers = new SoapHeader('http://soapserver.example.com/webservices', 'UserCredentials', $sh_param); 

// Prepare Soap Client 
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($headers));
```

This one results in nothing happening,

And then I thought maybe not SOAP but this resulted in nothing as well

```
<?php  
$username = "some-username";
 $password = "some-password";
  $remote_url = 'http://www.somedomain.com/path/to/file';
    // Create a stream 
    $opts = array(   'http'=>array(     
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
            ) );
 $context = stream_context_create($opts);
// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above 
$file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);
echo($file);
```

All I've been told is

"Please connect to the web service below and display the contents retrieved on a web page:

Web service URL: http://www.wesbite.com/something/details.php?wsdl
username: something
password: something

"
And I am blank. If anyone could please assist

Comment: Look into WSDL2PHP. There are a number of projects that create helper code.

Comment: After preparing your `$soapClient` you have to invoke the service, i.e. call a method `$soapClient -> mymethod($myarguments);`